# DIV between two floated images isn't sizing properly

Tags: css

I need to create a dialog box using custom images created by a designer. For purposes of this discussion, this the correct answer for my application. The dialog box must be able to withstand changes in width and height. This is easy to do with a table, but I want to maintain a table-less design, so I figured that I could do this using 3 rows of DIV's. For example, float an image to the left, float an image to the right, and put a DIV in between then with the image set to the background so that text can be entered over it.

Here is demo of my failed attempt to do this: (just one row shown)
http://www.seaburydesign.com/rounded/demo.html

As you can see, this almost working. But the DIV in the middle is only the size of the content inside of it, even though I have set the height and width. I need to keep the width flexible.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Unless you plan to have that URI working for the next decade or so you might try isolate the code and use a pastebin for posting it, so that future readers can follow the question and given answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the rounded corners of your images white instead of transparent, you can apply the background-image to the header-tag instead of the middle div. This will create the impression that the middle div has the same height as both images.

**Update**

If possible (depending on what browsers you need to support), you could do rounded corners with CSS3's border-radius property, instead of using images. That would be something like:

```
header {
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
   border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

You could also try this [border-radius CSS-generator](http://border-radius.com/) to find the properties that suit you best.

Comment: Unfortunately this will be over various places, such as gradients and images, to I cannot make the corners white. Yes, that would help greatly.

Comment: @ToddDavis Updated my answer with another solution. Don't know if it is applicable in this case though (depends on what browsers you need to support with the rounded corners).

Comment: Thanks. I would much prefer CSS rounded corners, but the designer in this case designed some custom borders that I need to use. Plus it will need to be supported by IE6. Not fun all around, but there ya go.

Answer (score 0):

The css `display: inline` in your container `div`'s voids any setting for `width`. Use `display: block; float: left; margin: 0 XXpx;` for your `div` (with XX being the width of the images on the sides).

Edit:
Concretely this would be:

```
div#yourdiv {
  background-image: url("images/module_header_bg.jpg");
  color: white;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 42px;
  width: auto;
}
```

and **both** img tags

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

This creates a dynamic sized box for your content, or you set width of the div to a specific value like `width: 300px` instead of `width: auto`.

Comment: Removing the inline (that was in there from previous attempts to make this work, thanks for catching that) fixed the sizing issue in terms of height, etc. Floating it left helps if I remove the width:100%. However the width continues to break the layout. I tried setting the margins on both the left and right sides, using positive and negative values, but it seems to keep running over. I'll try to re-upload the result in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line:

> display:inline;

Besides being useless in this case (the inline behavior is already working because of the floats) "inline" property doesn't allow you to set the element's width or height. For a clearer understanding, read [w3c's article](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-CSS21-20030915/visuren.html#inline-formatting).

Comment: Thanks - the display inline has been removed, and that fixes the height. But the width is still an issue.